# Intuitive explanation for why potential difference is distributed in proportion to resistances in a series circuit?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, potential-energy, voltage

This is an easy question, but I'm looking for an intuitive explanation for why the total emf of a series circuit is distributed among its resistors in proportion to their resistances.

Or in other words, why isn't the potential difference equal across all resistors if they have different resistances, since the total resistors give a total resistance and hence a total current? So shouldn't the potential difference distributed across each one be equal?

Comment: [This may help you](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/519821).

Comment: @Doubtnut Thank you, this helped! What I don't understand about this answer though is the fact voltage is distributed across each resistor 'locally', when really a resistor contributes to the total effective resistance. I don't see how a resistor can behave as a stand-alone component and receive its own voltage when its part of an entire circuit.

Comment: I didn't understand the statement :"receive it's own voltage when it's part of an entire circuit ".